# How to read local entries in a service deployed on WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to access a local entry in an Axis2 service that is deployed on WSO2ESB. After deployment of a Carbon app, local entries are not copied into related synapse-config folder but wrote directly to database, I think. Therefore, I seek a solution other than just reading the local entry from `$ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/local-entries`. Is there a way to do that?